# PHP file paths work differently on developer machine

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, filepath

For some reason this path works perfectly on one developer's machine

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/../includes/init.php';
```

But on my machine I have to remove the '/..' section for it to work.

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/init.php';
```

I suspect this is linked other issues with the application on my machine.

Why is this occurring and what can I change to get it working like it does on the original developer's machine?

Comment: It's probebly because on the dev-machine you're using a subfolder while on the other machine the documents are already in the http-root. Meaning it can't go to a top-level map anymore.

Comment: Operating system, PHP version, File structure?

Comment: Always use absolute filepaths.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. Not sure about the developer. PHP 5.5.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois if we used absolute file paths, we'd need to use different paths for every developers machine.

Comment: @Julian Not really. You just have to define a constant in a global file (in the http root) and use this constant to create absolute filepaths.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered something similar, I used the `getcwd()` function in `PHP` to see that the working directory is different.

I managed to solve it by chdir to the current directory at start, and the relative paths have been working ever since.

Or you can use absolute paths.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` on each of the dev machines. Ensuring you're working from the same directory etc.

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
echo $path;
?>
```